# What axioms are needed in proofs of the independence of the continuum hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing, reverse-math

My understanding is that the proofs that CH and not-CH are consistent with ZFC are both *about* ZFC and *in* ZFC. **Is it possible to do these proofs *about* ZFC but *in* a weaker axiomatic system?**

(It is also my understanding that there are multiple methods of proving "CH is independent of ZFC". I'm interested in the question of if there is *any* way of proving this in a weaker system, and I'm interested in *either* direction (ZFC+CH or ZFC+not-CH).)

Comment: Yes, you can do the entire thing in $\sf PA$, and even weaker systems. Namely, $\sf PA\vdash\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)\rightarrow\operatorname{Con}(ZFC+CH) \land\operatorname{Con}(ZFC+\lnot CH)$.

Comment: Cool. Where can I learn more?

Comment: Probably the old Kunen book. I know that through Boolean-valued models you can also prove this, although I'm not 100% sure as to how this translates to a proof from within $\sf PA$. I saw some M.Sc. thesis once that had the details written out.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to leave the question open in the hopes that someone will drop in with a solid reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These independence proofs only use elementary finitistic reasoning. Finitistic reasoning itself could be formalized as PRA (primitive recursive arithmetic). PRA is a much weaker system than PA let alone ZFC. The proof theoretic ordinal of PRA is just $\omega^\omega$. Most mathematicians regard statements provable in PRA as *really true* (with the exception of perhaps *ultrafinitists*).

In a sense, the independence results really show in a strictly finitistic and constructive way how one could transform a proof of $0=1$ from ZFC+(not)CH into a proof of $0=1$ from ZFC alone.

Some remarks about this can be found in the book *Set Theory* (2013 by Kenneth Kunen) (Chapter II.1 Informal Remarks on Consistency Proofs).